# How to differentiate between app being minimized and the screen being locked in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have an app that has a Timer counting down to zero, currently I am using AppLifecycleState.paused to check if the app is in the background so I can pause the timer, my problem is I want the Timer to continue if the user locks the screen. When they have the app open and both the app being minimized and the screen being locked make a AppLifecycleState.paused. How do I know if the user locked the screen vs opening another app or returning to the Home Screen in Flutter?